# Как сделать так чтобы при выборе объекта в QListView создавался такой объект

Tags: python, pyqt5, drag-n-drop, qlistview, qstandarditemmodel

Я хотел сделать что-то на подобии *Qt Designer*, но не могу сделать это.
Мне нужно чтобы объект перетаскивался.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я не совсем понял что и куда вы собираетесь перетаскивать, но небольшой пример вам покажу. Пожалуйста всегда публикуйте минимально-воспроизводимый пример, который демонстрирует проблему и лучше рассказывайте что вы хотите сделать.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class LListView(QtWidgets.QListView):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(LListView, self).__init__(parent)
        
        self.m_model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel(self)
        self.setModel(self.m_model)

        self.setAcceptDrops(False)
        self.setEditTriggers(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.NoEditTriggers)
        self.setResizeMode(QtWidgets.QListView.Adjust)
        self.setDragDropMode(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.DragOnly)


class RListView(QtWidgets.QListView):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(RListView, self).__init__(parent)
        
        self.m_model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel(self)
        self.setModel(self.m_model)

        self.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.setEditTriggers(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.NoEditTriggers)
        self.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(50, 50))
        self.setResizeMode(QtWidgets.QListView.Adjust)
        self.setDragDropMode(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.DropOnly)

    def dropEvent(self, event):
        last_row_count = self.model().rowCount()
        super(RListView, self).dropEvent(event)
        if self.model().rowCount() > last_row_count:
            md = event.mimeData()
            fmt = "application/x-qabstractitemmodeldatalist"
            if md.hasFormat(fmt):
                encoded = md.data(fmt)
                stream = QtCore.QDataStream(encoded, QtCore.QIODevice.ReadOnly)
                datas = []
                item = {}
                while not stream.atEnd():
                    row = stream.readInt32()
                    column = stream.readInt32()
                    map_items = stream.readInt32()
                    for i in range(map_items):
                        key = stream.readInt32()
                        value = QtCore.QVariant()
                        stream >> value
                        item[QtCore.Qt.ItemDataRole(key)] = value
                    datas.append(item)


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.centralWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)
        
        self.l_view = LListView()
        self.r_view = RListView()

        lay = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.centralWidget)
        lay.addWidget(self.l_view)
        lay.addWidget(self.r_view)

        for i in range(5):
            item = QListWidgetItem() 
            it = QtGui.QStandardItem("item"+str(i))
            self.l_view.model().appendRow(it)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**Update:**

> Да я это видел но мне нужно чтобы если я выберу pushbutton то он у меня создалось

Это хорошо что вы уже кое-что видели. Плохо что вы не показываете свои попыток сделать то что вы хотите.

Как возможный вариант и очень приблизительно, это может выглядеть так:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class LListView(QtWidgets.QListView):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(LListView, self).__init__(parent)
        self.m_model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel(self)
        self.setModel(self.m_model)
        self.setAcceptDrops(False)
        self.setEditTriggers(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.NoEditTriggers)
        self.setResizeMode(QtWidgets.QListView.Adjust)
        self.setDragDropMode(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.DragOnly)


class RListView(QtWidgets.QListView):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(RListView, self).__init__(parent)
        self.m_model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel(self)
        self.setModel(self.m_model)
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.setEditTriggers(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.NoEditTriggers)
        self.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(50, 50))
        self.setResizeMode(QtWidgets.QListView.Adjust)
        self.setDragDropMode(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.DropOnly)

    def dropEvent(self, event):
        last_row_count = self.model().rowCount()
        super(RListView, self).dropEvent(event)
        if self.model().rowCount() > last_row_count:
            md = event.mimeData()
            fmt = "application/x-qabstractitemmodeldatalist"
            if md.hasFormat(fmt):
                encoded = md.data(fmt)
                stream = QtCore.QDataStream(encoded, QtCore.QIODevice.ReadOnly)
                datas = []
                item = {}
                while not stream.atEnd():
                    row = stream.readInt32()
                    column = stream.readInt32()
                    map_items = stream.readInt32()
                    for i in range(map_items):
                        key = stream.readInt32()
                        value = QtCore.QVariant()
                        stream >> value
                        item[QtCore.Qt.ItemDataRole(key)] = value
                    datas.append(item)
                  
                    
class DemoWidget(QtWidgets.QFrame):
    def __init__(self, widgets, parent):
        super().__init__(parent) 
     
        self.widgets = widgets
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.setStyleSheet('DemoWidget {background-color: #D98C00;}')

    def dragEnterEvent(self, event):
        event.accept()
        
    def dropEvent(self, event):
        for name in self.widgets:
            mimeData = event.mimeData().data('application/x-qabstractitemmodeldatalist')            
            if name in str(mimeData, 'utf-8').replace('\x00', ''):
                if name == 'pushButton':
                    widget = QPushButton()
                elif name == 'label':
                    widget = QLabel() 
                    widget.setStyleSheet('QLabel {background-color: #B5FE83;}')                     
                elif name == 'lineEdit':
                    widget = QLineEdit()                      
                widget.setParent(self)
                widget.setText(name)
                widget.move(event.pos())
                widget.show()
                break


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.centralWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)
        
        self.l_view = LListView()
        self.r_view = RListView()
        self.r_view.setMaximumHeight(80) 

        self.widgets = [
            'pushButton', 
            'lineEdit',  
            'label', 
        ]
        
        self.demoWidget = DemoWidget(self.widgets, self)
        vlay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        vlay.addWidget(self.r_view)
        vlay.addWidget(self.demoWidget)

        lay = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.centralWidget)
        lay.addWidget(self.l_view, 1)
        lay.addLayout(vlay, 5)
        
        for name in self.widgets:
            item = QListWidgetItem() 
            it = QtGui.QStandardItem(f"{name}")
            self.l_view.model().appendRow(it)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.resize(500, 500)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Да я это видел но мне нужно чтобы если я выберу pushbutton то он у меня создалось

Comment: Брать ты лучший

Comment: почему если я первым перетаскаю lineEdit то прога останавливается

Comment: @АзамНегматов я проверил, у меня в моем примере ничего не останавливается. Если у вас есть другие вопросы - задайте новый вопрос. Приложите ваш пример. который демонстрирует проблему.

Comment: Вот я там ваш код изменил потому что она мне нужна я его в другой исходник кину но там вот ошибка @S. Nick вот ссылка https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1426750/508649