# Почему когда я перетаскаю объект в Pyqt то у меня прога вылетает

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, pyqt, drag-n-drop

В моем коде если я перетаскаю первой кнопку - все работает. Но если я перетаскаю первой  `QLineEdit`, то у меня прога выходит и даёт ошибку.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class DemoWidget(QtWidgets.QFrame):
    def __init__(self, widgets, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)

       self.widgets = widgets
       self.setAcceptDrops(True)
       self.setStyleSheet('DemoWidget {background-color: #D98C00;}')

    def dragEnterEvent(self, event):
       event.accept()

    def dropEvent(self, event):
       for name in self.widgets:
           mimeData = event.mimeData().data('application/x-qabstractitemmodeldatalist')
           if name in str(mimeData, 'utf-8').replace('\x00', ''):
                if name == 'pushButton':
                    self.widget = QPushButton()
                elif name == 'label':
                    self.widget = QLabel()
                    self.widget.setStyleSheet('QLabel {background-color: #B5FE83;}')
                elif name == 'lineEdit':
                    self.widget = QLineEdit()
                elif name == 'radibutton':
                    self.widget = QRadioButton()
                self.widget.setParent(self)
                self.widget.setText(name)
                self.widget.move(event.pos())
                self.widget.show()
                self.widget.installEventFilter(self)
                break

    def eventFilter(self, source, event):
        if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.MouseButtonPress and \
                event.button() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
            self.movingButton = source
            self.startPos = event.pos()
        elif event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.MouseMove and self.movingButton:
            self.movingButton.move(source.pos() + event.pos() - self.startPos)
        elif event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.MouseButtonRelease and self.movingButton:
            self.movingButton.move(source.pos() + event.pos() - self.startPos)
            self.movingButton = None
        return super().eventFilter(source, event)


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.centralWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)

        self.l_view = QtWidgets.QListView(self)
        self.m_model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel(self)
        self.l_view.setModel(self.m_model)
        self.l_view.setAcceptDrops(False)
        self.l_view.setEditTriggers(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.NoEditTriggers)
        self.l_view.setResizeMode(QtWidgets.QListView.Adjust)
        self.l_view.setDragDropMode(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.DragOnly)

        self.widgets = [
            'pushButton',
            'lineEdit',
            'label',
            'radibutton',
        ]

        self.demoWidget = DemoWidget(self.widgets, self)
        vlay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        vlay.addWidget(self.demoWidget)

        lay = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.centralWidget)
        lay.addWidget(self.l_view, 1)
        lay.addLayout(vlay, 5)

        for name in self.widgets:
            item = QListWidgetItem()
            it = QtGui.QStandardItem(f"{name}")
            self.l_view.model().appendRow(it)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.resize(500, 500)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**Вот ошибка:**

> Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы получать реальную ошибку - всегда запускайте свое приложение в CMD/консоли/терминале.

В конструкторе класса `DemoWidget` добавьте `self.movingButton = None`.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class DemoWidget(QtWidgets.QFrame):
    def __init__(self, widgets, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
# ---->>
        self.widgets = widgets
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.setStyleSheet('DemoWidget {background-color: #D98C00;}')
# ---->>
        self.movingButton = None                                            # !!! +++

    def dragEnterEvent(self, event):
       event.accept()

    def dropEvent(self, event):
       for name in self.widgets:
           mimeData = event.mimeData().data('application/x-qabstractitemmodeldatalist')
           if name in str(mimeData, 'utf-8').replace('\x00', ''):
                if name == 'pushButton':
                    self.widget = QPushButton()
                elif name == 'label':
                    self.widget = QLabel()
                    self.widget.setStyleSheet('QLabel {background-color: #B5FE83;}')
                elif name == 'lineEdit':
                    self.widget = QLineEdit()
                elif name == 'radibutton':
                    self.widget = QRadioButton()
                self.widget.setParent(self)
                self.widget.setText(name)
                self.widget.move(event.pos())
                self.widget.show()
                self.widget.installEventFilter(self)
                break

    def eventFilter(self, source, event):
        if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.MouseButtonPress and \
                event.button() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
            self.movingButton = source
            self.startPos = event.pos()
            
# !!!   AttributeError: 'DemoWidget' object has no attribute 'movingButton'     # !!! 
        elif event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.MouseMove and self.movingButton:
            self.movingButton.move(source.pos() + event.pos() - self.startPos)
        elif event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.MouseButtonRelease and self.movingButton:
            self.movingButton.move(source.pos() + event.pos() - self.startPos)
            self.movingButton = None
        return super().eventFilter(source, event)


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.centralWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)

        self.l_view = QtWidgets.QListView(self)
        self.m_model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel(self)
        self.l_view.setModel(self.m_model)
        self.l_view.setAcceptDrops(False)
        self.l_view.setEditTriggers(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.NoEditTriggers)
        self.l_view.setResizeMode(QtWidgets.QListView.Adjust)
        self.l_view.setDragDropMode(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.DragOnly)

        self.widgets = [
            'pushButton',
            'lineEdit',
            'label',
            'radibutton',
        ]

        self.demoWidget = DemoWidget(self.widgets, self)
        vlay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        vlay.addWidget(self.demoWidget)

        lay = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.centralWidget)
        lay.addWidget(self.l_view, 1)
        lay.addLayout(vlay, 5)

        for name in self.widgets:
            item = QListWidgetItem()
            it = QtGui.QStandardItem(f"{name}")
            self.l_view.model().appendRow(it)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.resize(500, 500)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо ты откуда знаешь столько @S.Nick

Comment: @АзамНегматов, пожалуйста. Читаю много. Если мои ответы учат вас чему-то новому - вы можете их отмечать не только как правильные, но и как полезные. Если вы не знаете, 
как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: А что какие книги вы читаете @S. Nick